# Create an odd number list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, numbers

i want to make an odd number list by using 'while' and 'for'

```
a = []
x = 1
while x < 101:
    if x % 2 != 0:
        a.append(x)
        x = x + 1
print(a)
```

but nothing happened... and other unrelated codes which is in another sentence are also not executed.
what is my problem?

Comment: Note that if you start with 1, you only have to add 2 at each step, rather than add 1 and test if the number is odd.

Comment: It's an indentation typo. The `x = x + 1` should be aligned with `if`.

Answer (score 4):

You should increase the value of `x` in each iteration and not only if the value is an odd number:

```
a = []
x = 1
while x < 101:
    if x % 2 != 0:
        a.append(x)
    x += 1
print(a)
```

Though this is probably for learning purposes note that you could achieve this using the `range` function as follows: `list(range(1,101, 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

When you increment x, it should be out of 'if' condition. increment should  happen under while

```
a = list()
x = 1
while x <101:
    if x%2 != 0:
        a.append(x)
    x += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range` function as well (for `for` loop) which handles the increment part in the loop as below:
**FOR LOOP:**

```
odd=[]
for i in range(101):
    if (i%2!=0):
        odd.append(i)
print (odd)
```

**WHILE LOOP**:

```
odd=[]
i = 1
while i<101:
    if i%2 != 0:
        odd.append(i)
    i+=1
print (odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
odd = [i for i in range(101) if i%2 != 0]
print(odd)
```

Comment: While this is a shorter solution, the question specifically asked for a solution using while and for.